# how to add different different key value in NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

Question: how to add different - different key value pair in NSMutableArray.

Already tried ::
here is my code :

```
var fulldetail : NSMutableArray?
var userid : String!

 self.userid = (response.result.value?.valueForKey("userid")) as? String

            print(self.userid)
            self.fulldetail?.addObject(self.userid)
            print(self.fulldetail)
```

I am getting my userid in userid variable but fulldetail array getting nil
so where am Igoing wrong??

Comment: at a guess, `self.fulldetail` has never been allocated, so it is nil.

Comment: You should post some more code to see where you define `fulldetail` (if you ever do). Also, why exactly do you need it to be optional? Unless you have to assign it a value from something that might be `nil`, you might as well just declare it as `NSMutableArray!`

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `fulldetail`

```
var fulldetail: NSMutableArray? = NSMutableArray()
```

**EDIT For Clarification**

If you need `fulldetail` to `Optional`, then you can just initialize it (or check for it to be `nil`) wherever you need to use it with something like the line below. If `fulldetail` is not `nil`, it will set `fulldeatil` to itself, else it will initialize a new `NSMutableArray`.

```
fulldetail = fulldetail ?? NSMutableArray()
```

If you do not need `fulldetail` to ever be `nil`, then it it best to initialize it when it is declared.

```
var fulldetail = NSMutableArray()
```

**EDIT 2**

You are looking for a `Dictionary` if you want a `key-value` pair.

```
// Specify you data types. It could be [String:AnyObject]
var fulldetails = [String:String]()

// Add data like this
fulldetails["userid"] = self.userid
```

Comment: If you are going to initialise it like that then you may as well change it to `var fulldetail=NSMutableArray()`

Comment: While this is likely correct, how do you know that this is actually the true reason? OP never specified if any code was removed.

Comment: @Paulw11 What if he were to set it to `nil` later on? I assumed he had a reason for it to be `Optional`.

Comment: In that case leaving it as an optional and initialising it when required would be the better approach.

Comment: @Arc676 I do not see any other reason as to why it would not work. Maybe my knowledge is too limited.

Comment: Well there's always the chance that the array was set to `nil` somewhere in between. As we do not have the full source code, there is no way to know what might happen to the variable between the declaration and the use.

Comment: Thanks @Arc676 and Paulw11 for the helpful insights.

Comment: thanx @Caleb its working for me..but i am getting value like this Optional((
    102
))
but i want value like Optional({
   
    userid = 102;
})@Arc676

Comment: means i want to add value with key in nsmuttable array. later i have to add key "message " with value "login success"

Comment: thanks @Caleb For your amazing help. Acually i am fully beginner in programming or in swift.. thanks again for help

Comment: @GovindRakholiya No problem! Happy coding!